# Convolutional network returning a matrix with a image as input

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to code a model that looks at an image with a grid and returns a matrix with the contents of that grid.

Here is an example of the input image:

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Yd0.png)

And this should be the output:

```
[30202133333,
12022320321,
23103100322,
13103110301,
22221301212,
33100210001,
11012010320,
21230233011,
00330223230,
02121221220,
23133103321,
23110110330]
```

With 0: Blue, 1: Pink, 2: Lavender, 3: Green

I have a hard time finding resources on how to do this. What would be the simpelst way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple design choices to generate this type of output. I suggest using Autoencoders.

Here is some information about Autoencoders taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) -

> An autoencoder is a type of artificial neural network used to learn
> efficient codings of unlabeled data (unsupervised learning).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) The
> encoding is validated and refined by attempting to regenerate the
> input from the encoding. The autoencoder learns a representation
> (encoding) for a set of data, typically for dimensionality reduction,
> by training the network to ignore insignificant data (“noise”).

While autoencoders are typically used to reconstruct the input, you have a slightly different problem of mapping the input to a specific matrix.
You'd want to set up the architecture by providing images as input and the corresponding matrices as your "labels." The architecture can be further optimized by using Convolutional layers instead of MLP layers.